# Working with Asynchronous Operations in ASP.NET 4.5

Tags: c#, asp.net, asynchronous, async-await, asp.net-2.0

i am using asp.net 2.0 and write this code for Asynchronous Operations. i have a dynamic number of iterations so i implemented a FOR loop to register a dynamic number of tasks to be done Asynchronous

My problem is that this code only registers the last iteration only and ignores the first 9 ones

please advice

```
    int itterations = 10;
    for (int i = 0; i < itterations; i++)
    {
        ViewState.Add("name",i.ToString());
        WSProxy3.WebService3 obj3=new WSProxy3.WebService3();

        BeginEventHandler beginHandler3 = new BeginEventHandler(BeginAsyncOperation3);
        EndEventHandler endHandler3 = new EndEventHandler(EndAsyncOperation3);
        EndEventHandler timeoutHandler3 = new EndEventHandler(TimeoutAsyncOperation3);
        object state3 = obj3;
        PageAsyncTask task3 = new PageAsyncTask(beginHandler3, endHandler3, timeoutHandler3, state3,true);

        Page.RegisterAsyncTask(task3);
    }
```

Comment: Do all of this using Task and TAP, then register a single task. Much simpler. You can use Task.WhenAll to join the subtasks.

Comment: what is  Task and TAP i don't understand .. and i don't know anything about 1 task and then joining sub-tasks .. could you please illustrate this more detailed

Comment: Please clarify the ASP.NET version you're targeting - you have written both 2.0 and 4.5.

Comment: Search for ".net call webservice task".